# Making joomla Extension in my own way

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I've tried to understand the structure of joomla. I've read many kinds of documents and tutorial regarding about how to make extensions in joomla. I can't able to understand it fully. I still had some doubts on it. I've made a simple component in joomla by using `MVC` concept and using some joomla core files. I won't say that it is like same as what professional are making it. I've used *30%* of joomla like using `MVC` concept, extending the core files of joomla and connected with the database using joomla syntax and some other ways also. Rest of the percent, i've used my own codes by using oops concept. So do you think that is it good enough to make an extension like this or i have to make an extension like that or i really have to learn and understand the official joomla way of making it's extension. I want to know it please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the joomla is given a brief details for developing its extensions.

You can check the following url for understanding the components structure of joomla.

http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/1.5/Introduction

In this doc at the end you can find a download link download the component and go through the code you will get full idea about joomla MVC concept.Its pretty simple.

I think no one can explain your requirement with what you are expecting.

Just keep this in mind while developing joomla's extensions.

1)Do not edit core file for your component task achievement.

2)Try to use jRequest  class for getting submitted values.

3)For new task use your controller overrided functions.

4)Make all your sql queries inside model only.

5)And make an extension that compact able for later version too.

These are the tips i can give you. 
Just walk through the code of some good extensions and try to follow that .

Hope this may help you..

Answer (score 0):

For ease of maintenance and for future development I would definitely recommend that you develop your component the right way. If you are going to release the component I would say that it is a requirement.

The who MVC structure can be confusing at first but once you get your head around it is really nice.

I would suggest making the MVC skeleton by using the Joomla Component Creator
http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/ and then add the custom code yourself.

Comment: I've made my extension through the help of notwebdesign.com component creator. It's a  very good website for making an extension in a very simple way.